# How to use .plugins folder across multiple workspace in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using customized eclipse helios and having multiple projects and so multiple workspaces, most of the projects having common source codes. 
When i create a workspace eclipse creating .metadata folder and inside which created .plugins folder for each workspace, my issue is, .plugins folder is about 2 GB, so whenever i create new workspace it is occupying 2GB for that workspace and it goes on for every workspace creation.

I want to use one common .plugins folder for all the workspaces, is it possible to do it in eclipse to refer the existing .plugins folder from other workspace?

Comment: The .plugins folders contain some information which is specific to a workspace so trying to share them is a very bad idea. The .metadata is not normally so large so it might be worth looking in more detail to see which plugin is using the space.

Comment: "org.maven.ide.eclipse" plugin alone is 871 MB and its the highest of all